# Swap lines in text file only where containing strings using sed or ed?

Tags: text-processing, sed, ed

I need to swap these lines, only where the matching strings are in both lines:

before:

```
REF*CE*-------------------------
REF*1W*-------------------------
```

after:

```
REF*1W*-------------------------
REF*CE*-------------------------
```

I tried this, it didn't work:

```
ed -s testfile.txt <<<$'/REF*CE*/-0,/REF*CE*/+0m/REF*1W*/\nw\nq'
```

Comment: *the matching strings* - by the prefix `REF` ?

Comment: REF*CE* and REF*1W* are matching strings

Comment: Literal asterisks, or RE followed by zero or more Fs, followed by C, followed by zero or more Es?

Comment: yes, if both patterns match, swap lines

Comment: Does your file contain other lines also?  Are the given lines adjacent?  How should non-adjacent REF lines be handled?  Might your file contain more than two lines with the pattern REF?  Should more pairs be swapped?  What if there are an odd number of REF lines?

Comment: I would recommend posting a better example of input and desired output.  Also please explain what didn't work with the items you posted below Blair M's answer

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/^\(REF\*CE.*\)\n\(REF\*1W.*\)/\2\n\1/;ta' -e 'P;D' <testfile.txt
```

1. If we're not on the last line then append next line.
2. Do a substitution on the current line that only occurs if it matches `substring containing pattern 1 + newline + substring containing pattern 2`. The substitution flips the two sub-strings. After substitution go back to label :a.
3. If there was no match Print the pattern space as is. Then Delete the pattern space and start the cycle again.

Sample with some surrounding lines...

```
In:

    XEF*CE*------------------------- 
    REF*CE*------------------------- 
    REF*1W*------------------------- 
    REF*2W*------------------------- 

Out:


    XEF*CE*------------------------- 
    REF*1W*------------------------- 
    REF*CE*------------------------- 
    REF*2W*-------------------------
```

More generally for any pattern1 and pattern2

```
sed -e :a \
    -e "\$!N; s/^\(.*${pattern1}.*\)\n\(.*${pattern2}.*\)/\2\n\1/;ta" \
    -e 'P;D' < inputfile
```

Comment: I tried the sed command on my test file, and it didn't work. Here is the relevant section of the file:     `REF*BB*106497026~`
   `REF*CE*NEW JERSEY~`
    `REF*1W*723266637~`
    `SVC*HC^S5102*78.5*78.5**1~`

Comment: Sorry, I should have tested a bit more. Hopefully this does the trick. Your testcases work for me.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution for how to swap two (possibly distant) lines that match particular regular expressions with `ed`:

1. *Copy* one line to after the second line.
2. *Move* the second line to after the original first line.
3. *Delete* the first original line.

Or, with `ed` editing commands:

1. `/pat1/t/pat2/`
2. `?pat2?m/pat1/`
3. `?pat1?d`

Example with [the file](https://www.1edisource.com/resources/edi-transactions-sets/edi-835/)

```
CLP*815900102*2*489.8*101.5*82.29*13*PVJLS03YP0000*13*7
AMT*AU*489.8
REF*6R*00000000002
DTM*472*20160528
CAS*OA*23*306.01
CAS*PR*2*82.29
SVC*HC:99212:25*489.8*101.5**1
AMT*B6*411.43
```

in which we'd like to swap the first `AMT` line with the second `CAS` line.  `pat1` will be `^AMT\*AU` and `pat2` will be `^CAS\*PR`. Note that we need to escape the `*` for it to be treated literally in the regular expression.

I have annotated the changes below so that it's easier to see them. The `XXX` indicates the current position in the file after each operation.

1. `/^AMT\*AU/t/^CAS\*PR/` produces

   ```
   CLP*815900102*2*489.8*101.5*82.29*13*PVJLS03YP0000*13*7
   AMT*AU*489.8        <-- Line copied *from* here
   REF*6R*00000000002
   DTM*472*20160528
   CAS*OA*23*306.01
   CAS*PR*2*82.29
   AMT*AU*489.8        <-- Line copied *to* here (XXX)
   SVC*HC:99212:25*489.8*101.5**1
   AMT*B6*411.43
   ```
2. `?^CAS\*PR?m/^AMT\*AU/` produces

   ```
   CLP*815900102*2*489.8*101.5*82.29*13*PVJLS03YP0000*13*7
   AMT*AU*489.8
   CAS*PR*2*82.29      <-- line moved here (XXX)
   REF*6R*00000000002
   DTM*472*20160528
   CAS*OA*23*306.01
   AMT*AU*489.8        <-- line previous to this deleted
   SVC*HC:99212:25*489.8*101.5**1
   AMT*B6*411.43
   ```
3. `?^AMT\*AU?d` produces

   ```
   CLP*815900102*2*489.8*101.5*82.29*13*PVJLS03YP0000*13*7
   CAS*PR*2*82.29      <-- the line before this was removed (XXX)
   REF*6R*00000000002
   DTM*472*20160528
   CAS*OA*23*306.01
   AMT*AU*489.8
   SVC*HC:99212:25*489.8*101.5**1
   AMT*B6*411.43
   ```

---

As an easy-to-remember "one-liner":

```
pat1='^AMT\*AU'; pat2='^CAS\*PR'; printf '/%s/t/%s/\n?%s?m/%s/\n?%s?d\nwq\n' "$pat1" "$pat2" "$pat2" "$pat1" "$pat1" | ed -s file
```

Note that this is reversible by running the exact thing a second time, i.e. it doesn't matter which pattern is the first or second.

Comment: Kusalananda, does this work if the pattern repeats multiple times in the file?

Comment: @user5586678 It will pick the first occurrence of each pattern.

Comment: @user5586678 Actually, the second step may become seriously messed up if `pat1` occurs many times. It would be best to try to have as specific patterns as possible.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the desired effect by  putting the matched line into hold buffer, reading next line and printing it, then swapping the hold buffer with pattern buffer and printing again.

```
bash-4.3$ sed -n '/^REF\*CE/!p;/^REF\*CE/{h;n;p;x;p}' input.txt
some line here
REF*BB*106497026---------------
REF*1W*723266637---------------
REF*CE*NEW JERSEY--------------
SVC*HC^S5102*78.5*78.5**1------
another line there
```

Comment: Doesn't work with the case cited in the first comment below my answer.

Comment: @BlairM. I just tested with the example OP mentioned. Works OK. Can you clarify what exactly doesn't work ?

Comment: As don_crissti mentioned try it where the first pattern repeats on consecutive lines. Mine didn't work with this case until I updated it. Yours seems to discard a line at some point.

Comment: @BlairM. OK, but what OP provided in the example isn't repeated consecutive lines. It's completely separate case, unless OP updates their example as I've requested

Comment: I would imagine that OP is not trying to solve only for the very specific case that he supplied and his comment to my answer suggests as much. Regardless I want my answer to be robust enough to work generally, matching consecutive patterned lines under any circumstance, so that other people may find it useful.

Comment: Blair, I put the commands above into a .sh file and ran it with the relevant patterns and got this error: ./filefix.sh: line 1: \$!N; s/^\(.*${REF*CE*}.*\)\n\(.*${REF*1W*}.*\)/\2\n\1/;ta: bad substitution

Comment: Actually I already see the issue. You're mixing the first, specific command with the second, general, command. The second one uses variables to contain the patterns. Try using the first one. If your patterns are not exactly the way I have them then modify them as necessary. You shouldn't have anything like `${foo}` if you're not putting your patterns in variables. If it's still not working post the _exact_ patterns you are trying to match.

Comment: @blair-m, thanks for the reply. I am putting the exact pattern in the commands, but stackexchange is removing some of the asterisks when i copy/paste.

Comment: @user5586678 If you are positive that you are correctly entering every backslash, single quote, space, etc. of the first line of my answer then my next question is what type of system are you running it on? And what version of sed are you using (`sed --version`)? (Add your replies under my answer for now on, please.)

Comment: Guys, maybe you should ask mods to move conversation to chat ?

Comment: @BlairM. Normally yes, but moderator can override that. On Ask Ubuntu at least it's done quite frequently

Comment: @BlairM, if you look at the original question it has the pattern strings(first part of line) followed by dashes. The dashes represent the variable part of the lines. I want to swap when both patterns match.

Comment: @user5586678 I'm out, man, sorry. You're not paying attention to what anyone is saying ("add better examples of input/output to your question", "explain what didn't work with Blair M's answer", "please reply under my answer, not here", etc.) and I don't have infinite time to spend on this.

Answer (score -1):

I have simple solution like this:
Say, If you want swap a line that has "XXXX" with line that has "YYYY" in afile, providing only one line has "XXXX" and only one has "YYYY"

Example file is like this:
   ssss dddd
 
   aaaa ffff
 
   ddd rrrr
   ddddd XXXX 
   ddddde
 
   ffff
   ffff
 
   fff
 
   eeee YYYY
   ghghgh
 
   hhhhh

My 'sed' command is sed 's/XXXX/ZZZZ/g;s/YYYY/XXXX/g;s/ZZZZ/YYYY/g' 
Remember "ZZZZ" string should not be in the file anyware.

Comment: But this doesn’t swap the ***lines**;*  it leaves `ddddd` and `eeee` where they are.

Comment: Then do hole line as string. eg: instead of 'XXXX' do 'ddddd XXXX'
I had a situation to swap a string in two lines. Rest of the strings in those lines were same. That is why I was looking for a solution to swap two lines. The solution that I made works for my problem. But if you want to swap whole lines, the way I did will give you an idea.